# how to get the most value training data under tensorflow framework

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

In case I want to add more training data to an existing classification model. Since the cost of labeling training data is high, I just want to label the most value data to the existing model.

For example, we only have two classes(A/B) in our classification problem, then use the existing model to predict three un-label data, and get the probability distribution:

```
 Data                A   B
Case 1: features -> 0.9 0.1
Case 2: features -> 0.6 0.4
Case 3: features -> 0.5 0.5
```

Case 3 should be the most value training data since current model doesn't know which class it belongs to. Is it right? if so, entropy should be a good metrics here, but I just can't find the implementation of `tf.reduce_entropy` in [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/math_ops#Reduction)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the scipy implementation for entropy? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.entropy.html

```
scipy.stats.entropy(pk)
```

You can get the predictions for your unlabeled data, then calculate entropy for each of the predictions.

Hope this helps!